# http provider/data source - lazy or eager?

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this data clause first:

```
data "http" "json_pattern" {
  url = "${var.cloudwatch_event_pattern_json_url}"
}
```

the variable will be something like this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexakarpov/ak_terr/master/pattern.json

, i.e. just a JSON object which is a pattern for an event in CloudWatch

and then, I have a resource block:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "event_pattern_rule" {
  count         = "${var.cloudwatch_event_pattern_json_url == "" ? 0 : 1}"
  name          = "${var.name}-json-event-trigger"
  description   = "Event to trigger the execution of the lambda function: ${var.name}"
  event_pattern = "${data.http.json_pattern.body}"
}
```

What I want to know - will this http call happen as many times as this file is processed, or only as many times as the condition in

> count = "..."

matches ? To put it in other way, is that http call going to be lazy, only executing when a resource is provisioned (case of count == 1 here)? Or is it eagerly executed every time the file is loaded? Sounds like a question only a real guru could answer, while I'm just a week into this IAC hell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html#data-source-lifecycle) the state of a data source will be "updated during Terraform's 'refresh' phase, which by default runs prior to creating a plan." So that'd mean that it's called once

If you easily want to verify it yourself, create a [RequestBin](https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/) and use the given URL in your Terraform configuration. After giving the page a refresh, you can see what requests are made.

Comment: great suggestion, too - I was contemplating starting an instance of Apache, to monitor access logs, but this is obviously a better choice